# Autoloading Image modal with HTML, CSS, and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am trying to add an image that pops up for mobile viewers upon website entrance. I have a rough idea of the things that must go into the code but not sure exactly how to put things together. Could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

I am using cargo collective to build my website if that helps.
I'd like to do something similiar to: https://badbadbadbad.com/ (whenever viewed on a phone)

- J

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's onload function to make an action happen when a page loads. Example below just shows an alert box with some text, but it's a start.

Post your code and we can help further.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pop Up on Page Load</title>
        <script>
            document.onload(alert("This is my image."));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is my website.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jec07b2o/).

```
HTML:
<div class="regularBox"></div>
<div class="modalBox">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/02/22/16/apple-blossoms-1368187_960_720.jpg">
  <span class="close">&times</span> <!--Click X to close-->
  </div>

JS: 
function showPopup() {
  document.querySelector('.modalBox').style.display = 'block';
}
showPopup(); // show modal image. 

function closePopUp() {
  document.querySelector('.modalBox').style.display = 'none';
}

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', closePopUp); // hide modal image

CSS: 
img {
  width: 80%;

}

.close {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalBox {
  display: none;

}

.regularBox {
  z-index: -1; // placed behind modalbox
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 400px;
```

Comment: This is a great start for me thank you so much. I've found the image doesn't "float" over the other contents of the page but instead pushes them further down. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: Try using z-index: -1 on other contents and position absolute. The fiddle is also updated. To get a better understanding of layers I advise you to experiment with positions (relative, absolute etc.), z-index and how placements of divs inside of divs affects the layout. A nice trick is to use opactiy: 0.6; (css) so that you can "see" through the different layers while working.

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! Now I need to figure out how to close it by clicking on it rather than the "X" and how to get it to only open on phone size screens.

Comment: Simply change the the selection of the class to .modalBox : document.querySelector('.modalBox').addEventListener('click', closePopUp);

Comment: Okay so I am trying to make the image load only on certain size screens which would be the standard size phone screen. Anything under 500px I suppose? Here is my code but it doesn't seem to be working. Also I really appreciate all of your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/0jLxzm35/ (I removed the img url from the html to see if it would only load with CSS but it wasn't working for me)

Comment: You were almost there. Try adding height and width in the CSS for the modalbox and then minimize the window until it hits 600px and see the magic :)  https://jsfiddle.net/0jLxzm35/